How high and low surrogates and type it out with the command on latex?
Because I can’t type characters above U+10000 using Overleaf. If I type them directly, they will turn into question marks. If you know, can you teach me?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

high/low surrogates are a feature of UTF-16 which is not used at Overleaf. Like this site and most of the web, and latex, it uses UTF-8.  You can enter the full unicode range directly if your keyboard input allows it.
